# C++ copying a string array[] to a vector <string>

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

So i'm making this class with a member function "insert" to copy from a string array to the classes contents which is a vector  array.

This abort error keeps popping up saying i'm going past the Vector end, but i don't understand why....

Here's the code:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////      Map class   /////////////////////
class Map
{
private:
///////////////////////////////////////////     Map Variables ///////////////
    string _name;
    vector <string> _contents;

public:
    Map(string name){_name = name;
                     _contents.reserve(56);};
    ~Map(){};
    string getName()
    {
    return _name;
    };

    vector <string> getContents()
    {
        return _contents;
    };

///////////////////////////////////////////     Insert  ////////////////////////
            //  string* to an array of 56 strings;
    bool Insert(string* _lines_)
    {

    for (int I = 0; I < 3; I++)
    {
        _contents[I] = _lines_[I];
    }
        return true;
    };


};
```

If you need any more info just ask! **Thanks!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, you don't need copy them yourself. You can use `std::vector::assign` to convert a `c-style array` to an `std::vector`.

**vector::assign**

Assigns new content to the vector object, dropping all the elements contained in the vector before the call and replacing them by those specified by the parameters.

**Example**

```
string sArray[3] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
vector<string> sVector;
sVector.assign(sArray, sArray+3);
        ^ ok, now sVector contains three elements, "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"
```

**More details**

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/assign/

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::copy` as:

```
#include <algorithm> //for std::copy
#include <iterator>  //for std::back_inserter

std::copy(_lines_, _lines_ + count, std::back_inserter(_contents));
```

where `count` is the total number of strings in the array. If the total number of strings is `56`, the `count` should be `56`, not `55` (if you want all strings to be copied to `_contents`).

Answer (score 1):

The vector doesn't have a size (just some space `reserve`ed).

You either have to `resize()` the vector, or use `push_back()` to add the new elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should resize `vector <string> _contents` before you can add any elements using the subscript [] operator.

Also: provide a default constructor your Map class.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're not supposed to use underscore prefixed identifiers
2. Assign `_name` in the initializer list: `Map(string name) : _name(name) {`
3. `_contents` has enough capacity for 56 elements but has no actual elements. You should either resize it (`_contents.resize(56);`), add elements to it in the `Insert` method (`_contents.push_back(_lines_[I]);`), or construct it with enough capacity (add `, _contents(56)` to the initializer list).

Answer (score 0):

It is now much simpler. (C++11)

```
string sArray[3] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
vector<string> sVector (sArray, sArray + 3);
```

No copy, assign is need.