# how to copy array of string to dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++

i just want to copy array of string to dynamical array(using new operator) without using string.h of c++
how can i copying the array?

```
enter code here
const int LEN=3;
int n=15;
char*s1 ;
char *s[LEN]={"music","disc","soft"};
char (*str)[LEN]=new char[n][LEN];   //i want to copy s to  this array
```

i try to do something like this

```
for(int i=0; i<LEN ;i++){
     strcpy(str[i],s[i]);
}
for(int i=0; i<LEN ;i++)
      cout<<str[i]<<endl;
```

but it printing all  the array in one Sequence, i think a problem with NULL terminator 
i don't no how to deal with

Comment: [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). And `new char[n][LEN];` is wrong.

Comment: Missing `const`, unused variable `s1`, and obsolete comment...

Comment: Don’t use `char*` in C++, please. It just hurts, and 99% of the time, proper `std::string` is what you want. Also, please use `std::vector` (or maybe `std::array`), even if it means typing a little more.

Comment: The requirement is to do without using standard string class

Comment: @DanielHailemichael: Then change the requirement. Writing C++ in the style of C is a recipe for heartache and pain.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I assume that's to be read as "the assignment requires".. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invert the dimension of `str`, try:

```
const int LEN = 3;
const int n = 15;
const char *s[LEN] = {"music", "disc", "soft"};
char (*str)[n] = new char[LEN][n];

for(int i = 0; i < LEN ; i++) {
    strncpy(str[i], s[i], n);
}
for(int i = 0; i < LEN ; i++)
    std::cout << str[i] << std::endl;

delete []str;
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/f99aba)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

```
string sArray[3] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
vector<string> sVector;
sVector.assign(sArray, sArray+3);
```

Source from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839499/c-copying-a-string-array-to-a-vector-string)

Answer (score 1):

Sane C++ code would use `vector` or `array`, and also `string`.  However, without those, pure C would often use a dynamic array of dynamic strings:

```
char** strs = new char*[LEN];  //a dynamic array of dynamic strings
//Alternatively, char* (*strs)[LEN]
for(int i=0; i<LEN; ++i) {
    strs[i] = new char[strlen(s[i])];
    strcpy(strs[i], s[i]);
}
//code goes here
for(int i=0; i<LEN; ++i) 
    delete[] strs[i];
delete[] strs;
strs = NULL;
```

However, your code is closer to a dynamic array of fixed length strings:

```
char **strs = new char[n][LEN];  //a dynamic array of dynamic strings
//Alternatively, char(*strs)[LEN][n], or is it char(*strs)[n][LEN]?
for(int i=0; i<LEN; ++i) 
    strcpy(strs[i], s[i]);
//code goes here
delete[] strs;
strs = NULL;
```